# .htacces redirect from domain 1 to domain 2 subdir, keeping path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have found plenty of useful answers in this forum that got me to the point I'm at, however the configuration of my .htaccess redirect is still not 100% perfect.

**Set-up**

I have two domains registered:

- `domain1.is` (only domain)
- `domain2.me` (domain + hosting)

The domain1 redirects as wildcard everything to domain2.

**What I'm trying to do**

I have installed yourls (url shortened) on `domain2.me/yourls` and want to redirect all `domain1.is/randomstring` to  `domain2.me/yourls/randomstring`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.is$
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain2.me/yourls/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ store [L,R=301]
```

**The issue**

So far I got that `domain1.is/randomstring` goes to  `domain2.me/randomstring`, however the subdirectory in the .htacess file seems to be completely ignored, effectively rendering the whole system unusable.

I've tried adding a condition, changing the subdirectory, etc. but can't seem to find the reason why. Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance and cheers from Berlin!

Comment: We cannot help without the current rewriting rules. Please add them as soon as you can.

Comment: @arkascha done! Sorry it took a while :)

Comment: _“So far I got that `domain1.is/randomstring` goes to `domain2.me/randomstring`”_ - that’s what you had before already: _“domain1 redirects as wildcard everything to domain2”_ And because of that already existing redirect, which presumably happens earlier/on a higher level, I bet `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.is$` never becomes true here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I suspected that could be the case, but I'm a novice with .htaccess and not sure how to test it.

Comment: I think your only option with this setup is to rewrite or redirect `domain1.is/randomstring`, once the user lands there. If you can rewrite just anything matching that format, as long as it does not match any physically existing file or folder, that should be easy enough (research how to perform that kind of check while rewriting, if you don’t know.) But if you have other “fake” URLs of that same format, that need to be redirected/rewritten elsewhere … then you would either need to try and be more specific as to what `randomstring` can actually look like, or add exceptions for specific URLs.

Comment: The `randomstring` can be any set of letters & numbers ONLY up to 16chars of length. I don't have hosting on domain1.is, however since I only use domain1.is to do redirects, I tried to set up a wildcard redirect to domain2.me/yourls .. The DNS are updating, let's see if this work. Thanks for the hint meanwhile @CBroe .

Comment: Ok this didn't work. Now the redirection ends in the subdirectory, but it's causing conflicts with the existing .htaccess from yourls, ending up in an endless redirect loop. Moreover, I don't have a chance to check if the original `randomstring` has been carried over either. Maybe I should start from scratch. Any suggestion on a better approach @CBroe ? (happy to share more if needed)

Comment: _“Moreover, I don't have a chance to check if the original randomstring has been carried over either.”_ - should be able to see that in your browser dev tools, network panel, if you keep logging enabled. If you can get `domain1/foobar` to redirect to `domain2.me/yourls/foobar`, then I don’t see how that should not work, it would be little different to the user entering the 2nd URL directly.

Comment: @CBroe I rewrote the DNS to do a wildcard redirect to the subdirectory and didn't even have to touch .htaccess. It worked (I was impatient and didn't wait for the DNS to updates, hence my impression it didn't work). Thanks a lot for your help and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share my solution in case someone else stumbles upon this conversation. The details/history are in the comments of the question.

## TLDR;

Just set up a wildcard redirect to the subdirectory.
[image: DNS records]

(not sure if the first redirect is useful, but still).
Important point: you don't even need to touch the `.htaccess` file (in my particular case yourls already had one, so I left it as it is).

*Credit: thanks @CBroe for pointing me in the right direction.*